# How to install slack desktop 2.6.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS?

Tags: slack

My issue was that even after I [downloaded](https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-2.6.3-amd64.deb) slack, and I did:

```
cd ~/Downloads
dpkg -i slack-desktop-2.6.3-amd64.deb
```

I got errors about missing `libappindicator1`.

So I do the next logical thing right?

`sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`, this too resulted in an error. Oh well, jeez I though, I know this is beta, but really? I can't even install it with one command?

How to resolve this? Read my one line answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the complete solution:

1. `cd ~/Downloads`
2. `wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-2.6.3-amd64.deb`
3. `sudo dpkg -i ./slack-desktop-2.6.3-amd64.deb`

Once you receive some errors: Try to run:

```
`sudo apt-get -f install`
```

to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You now can install Slack with "one command" :). It's now in the [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/slack) which means you can install it with:-

```
snap install slack --classic
```

Alternatively you'll find it in the Ubuntu Software application, just search for Slack and click 'Install'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way through which you can install slack on Ubuntu. Just run these commands on terminal

**Step 1 :** Type the following wget command to download the package:

```
https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-4.0.2-amd64.deb
```

**Step 2 :** Now install Slack by running the following command :

```
sudo apt install ./slack-desktop-*.deb
```

Hope this helps you!